# How to surround visual block with quotes (or similar) in vim

Tags: vim

Given a visual block selection in Vim, how does one wrap quotes around it?

I often find myself with the objective to take a list of fields - such as

```
name
address
telephone
```

to transform it into something like this in my code

```
declare name      = 'name';
declare address   = 'address';
declare telephone = 'telephone';
```

I'm comfortable getting to the following stage with a series of visual block selects and changes, etc.

```
declare name      = 'name
declare address   = 'address
declare telephone = 'telephone
```

but how do I do the last part inserting the trailing quote and semi-colon in an efficient way? Having to do an ex-mode substitute here somehow feels wrong.

**Edit**: I recall Damian Conway demonstrating this here - ["More Instantly Better Vim" - 37:00](http://youtu.be/aHm36-na4-4#t=37m00s). It's hard to tell but is he taking advantage of something in the dragvisuals.vim plugin or something native to vim when he appends the last quotes?

Comment: Why don't you use regexp `:1,3s/\(.*\)/declare \1 = '\1';`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Visual Block

You can use `$` and `A` with visual block mode. You can probably use `gv` to restart the Visual block mode up again.

```
gv$A';<esc>
```

#### Substitution

Visually select your lines then do `:s/$/';`

#### Better Substitution

Forget doing the visual block business and other stuff. Just start with your list and do the following substitution:

```
:%s/.*/declare & = '&';/
```

You could do a visual range if you rather. If you want to keep indention at the beginning of the line do: `:%s/^\s*\zs.*/declare & = '&'/`

#### Sidebar: Alignment

You can use a the plugin, [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), to do alignment.

```
:Tabularize /\zs=
```

Other alignment plugins are: [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) and [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

#### Conclusion

I prefer the "Better Substitution" method and followed by `:Tabularize`.

For more information see:

```
:h visual-block
:h blockwise-operators
:h v_b_A
:h v_b_A_example
:h gv
:h /\zs
:h :s/\&
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match a visual selection in a regular expression like this: `'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V/'&'`. See regexp help for explanations.

For your specific example I would record a macro to transform the first line:

`qq^yeIdeclare ^[pa = '^[A';^[jq`

and then repeat it for the rest:

`2@q`

Let's go through this: `^yeIdeclare ^[pa = '^[A';^[j`

- `^` takes us to the start of the line
- `ye` copies the word
- `Ideclare ^]` inserts a phrase in front
- `p` pastes the copied word
- `a = '^]` inserts the equals sign and opening quote
- `A';^]` appends the closing quote and semicolon
- `j` goes to the next line

Of course, I would just record the macro by hitting `qq` and performing these actions.